# difference between using if _n_ =1 then do; and not using it with PRXPARSE() in SAS

Tags: sas

Created a dataset :

```
data x;
infile datalines truncover;
input name $100.;
datalines;
Deepanshu
How are you, deepanshu
dipanshu
deepanshu is a good boy
My name is deepanshu
Deepanshu Bhalla
Deepanshuuu
DeepanshuBhalla
Bhalla Deepanshu
;
run;
```

Wrote the following code :

```
data test;
set x;
if _n_ =1 then do;
retain re;
re = prxparse("s/(Deepanshu\s?Bhalla|bhalla\s?Deepanshu|Deepanshu)/Soumya Pandey/i");
end;
new_data = prxchange(re, -1, name);
proc print;
run;
```

and a similar one but without the

```
if _n_ =1 then do; end; retain;
```

```
data test;
set x;
re = prxparse("s/(Deepanshu\s?Bhalla|bhalla\s?Deepanshu|Deepanshu)/Soumya Pandey/i");
new_data = prxchange(re, -1, name);
proc print;
run;
```

Both of the testing codes gave the same result. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

DATA Step code blocks with the construct

```
if _n_ = 1 then do;
   ... 
end;
```

cause the interior statements to occur during only the 1st iteration of the implicit loop.

`Retain`ing a (non DATA SET) variable prevents its value from being reset to missing at the top of the implicit loop.  Retain can be used to initialize a variable with a literal value at compilation time and do not need a `if _n_=1` guard.  Initializations from an computation assignment or `INPUT` necessarily require the guard (except special situations such a `prxparse`).

For the case of interior statement `re = prxparse(...)`

As stated by @whymath the DATA Step compiler is being improved in each release of SAS and there are now some implicit guards against recompiling a static regular expression pattern.

You will see the same code construct used for initializing `hash` objects.

Tip of the day:

- If you do not specify an argument, the RETAIN statement causes the values of **all variables** that are created with INPUT or assignment statements to be retained from one iteration of the DATA step to the next.

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses `if _n_ = 1 then ...; retain ;` statements, which is a very good and practical programming technique, called initialization block. It will only executing at the first row when reading data and avoids compiling the regular expression for each iteration of data step.

However, This skill may considered old-fashioned. In the very new version of SAS(mine is SAS9.4M5), we don't need to write this initialization block any more, there is some internal parser optimization. Here is specification from [SAS Help Center](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p06i7305izsnvcn1ru9147suzyv5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

> If perl-regular-expression is a constant or if it uses the /o option, the Perl regular expression is compiled only once. Successive calls to PRXPARSE do not cause a recompile, but returns the regular-expression-id for the regular expression that was already compiled. This behavior simplifies the code because you do not need to use an initialization block (IF _N_ =1) to initialize Perl regular expressions.

So I prefer to use your second way, it is a true SASor's way.